# 'java -version' command in CMD

Tags: java, applet

When I run the 'java -version' command in Command Prompt, then it gives me the following information:

```
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Can I run a web page that hosts a Java Applet properly?

P.S.: I'm using Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: You can.  You don't even need Java on your system to *host* an applet.  The people running the applet need to have Java on *their* systems in order for it to work.

Comment: So, Why doesn't my Java Applet work on the client?

In fact, I'm a .NET developer and I run the project with Visual Studio 2008 and one of pages of my web application has a Java Applet in its HTML code.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Define "doesn't ... work". Without more details I would suggest something is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Java installed on the server to host a Java applet. Applets are executed on the client side. Apache server (do not confuse with Apache Tomcat) or similar is enough.